# Problem in creating package through "Package for Linux" in Mono 2.8

Tags: linux, macos, mono

I am using **mono 2.8** with **Visual Studio 2008**. I have installed **"mono-2.8-gtksharp-2.12.10-win32-9"**.
I am creating a windows application and its setup solution is working fine on Windows OS. But when I am creating package for Linux and follow the instruction from http://mono-tools.com/Package.aspx

Step-1 to Step-5 are done but after Step-5, I am clicking on **Create Package** and its do nothing even its not create any file into selected folder.

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

When you choose the host for it to build the package on, make sure you are choosing a SUSE or RHEL server, or the process will silently fail.